# Is there a better way to extract information from a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Let's say I have an array of strings, and I need specific info from them, what would be an easy way to do that?

Suppose the array is this:

```
let infoArr = [
  "1 Ben Howard 12/16/1988 apple",
  "2 James Smith 1/10/1999 orange",
  "3 Andy Bloss 10/25/1956 apple",
  "4 Carrie Walters 8/20/1975 peach",
  "5 Doug Jones 11/10/1975 peach"
];
```

Let's say I want to extract the date and save it into another array, well I could make a function like this

```
function extractDates(arr)
{
  let dateRegex = /(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g, dates = "";
  let dateArr = [];

  for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
  {
    dates = /(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g.exec(arr[i])
    dates.pop();
    dateArr.push(dates);
  }

  return dateArr.flat();
}
```

Although this works, it is clunky and requires `pop()` because it will return an array of arrays, ie: `["12/16/1988", "16/"]`, plus I need to call `flat()` afterwards.

Another option would be to substring the strings, with a given position, where I need to know a regex pattern.

```
function extractDates2(arr)
{
  let dates = [];

  for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
  {
    let begin = regexIndexOf(arr[i], /(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g);
    let end = regexIndexOf(arr[i], /[0-9] /g, begin) + 1;
    dates.push(arr[i].substring(begin, end));
  }

  return dates;
 }
```

And of course it uses the next `regexIndexOf()` function:

```
function regexIndexOf(str, regex, start = 0)
{
  let indexOf = str.substring(start).search(regex);
  indexOf = (indexOf >= 0) ? (indexOf + start) : -1;
  return indexOf;
}
```

Again this function also works, but it seems too awful to accomplish the extraction of something simple. Is there an easier way to extract data into an array?

Comment: Why not use array.map?

Comment: @HenryHoweson `.map` (alone) won't work if there's more than one date in one of the input strings, eg `"1 Ben Howard 12/16/1988 apple 1/10/1999 "`, he'd have to flatten it afterwards

Comment: @CertainPerformance With the regex global flag set it would work fine, also the OP doesn't appear to require that.

Comment: @HenryHoweson Just using the global flag doesn't allow for (concise) extraction of matches from *multiple* strings into a *single* array, I thought? What code are you thinking of?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One option would be to join the strings by a separator that won't be matched, like `,`, then just perform the global match to get an array of dates from it:

```js
let infoArr = [
  "1 Ben Howard 12/16/1988 apple",
  "2 James Smith 1/10/1999 orange",
  "3 Andy Bloss 10/25/1956 apple",
  "4 Carrie Walters 8/20/1975 peach",
  "5 Doug Jones 11/10/1975 peach"
];
const result = infoArr
  .join(',')
  .match(/(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works great, and is very concise and easy to reason about.

Comment: This solution appears to be the quickest: http://jsben.ch/w9geK
additionally it has the advantage that it handles array elements without dates (doesn't create null values in the array), do keep in mind however that if you are trying to get the date of a specific element by its' index based on the original array then it may not line up if some elements don't have dates

Comment: This doesn't work when the `infoArr` is empty or none of the strings contains a date, as then `match()` returns `null` instead of an array. There's no reason to use `join` here, `map` or `flatMap` are much more reasonable.

Answer (score 21):

One approach could be using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the elements of the array applying the match on each element, and finally call [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get the desired result:

```js
let infoArr = [
  "1 Ben Howard 12/16/1988 apple",
  "2 James Smith 1/10/1999 orange",
  "3 Andy Bloss 10/25/1956 apple",
  "4 Carrie Walters 8/20/1975 peach",
  "5 Doug Jones 11/10/1975 peach"
];

const result = infoArr.map(o => o.match(/(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g)).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you could use [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
let infoArr = [
  "1 Ben Howard 12/16/1988 apple",
  "2 James Smith 1/10/1999 orange",
  "3 Andy Bloss 10/25/1956 apple",
  "4 Carrie Walters 8/20/1975 peach",
  "5 Doug Jones 11/10/1975 peach"
];

const result = infoArr.flatMap(o => o.match(/(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g));

console.log(result);
```

Also, if you need to remove `null` values from the final array in the case there are strings without dates, you can apply `filter()`, like this:

```
const result = infoArr.map(o => o.match(/(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g))
                      .flat()
                      .filter(date => date !== null);

const result = infoArr.flatMap(o => o.match(/(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g))
                      .filter(date => date !== null);
```

## An example with conflicting data:

```js
let infoArr = [
  "1 Ben Howard 12/16/1988 apple 10/22/1922",
  "2 James Smith orange",
  "3 Andy Bloss 10/25/1956 apple",
  "4 Carrie Walters 8/20/19075 peach",
  "5 Doug Jones 11/10-1975 peach"
];

const result = infoArr.flatMap(o => o.match(/(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g))
                      .filter(date => date !== null); /* or filter(date => date) */

console.log(result);
```

## Alternative without flat():

Since `flat()` and `flatMap()` are still currently "experimental", subject to change, and some browser (or versions)  don't support it, you can use next alternative with the limitation that will only get the first match on every `string`:

```js
const infoArr = [
  "1 Ben Howard 12/16/1988 apple 10/22/1922",
  "2 James Smith orange",
  "3 Andy Bloss 10/25/1956 apple",
  "4 Carrie Walters 8/20/19075 peach",
  "5 Doug Jones 11/10-1975 peach"
];

const getData = (input, regexp, filterNulls) =>
{
    let res = input.map(o =>
    {
        let matchs = o.match(regexp);
        return matchs && matchs[0];
    });

    return filterNulls ? res.filter(Boolean) : res;
}

console.log(getData(infoArr, /(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g, false));
console.log(getData(infoArr, /(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g, true));
```

Comment: You will end up with `null` values in the array if any of the lines don't contain dates.

Comment: @Shidersz add .filter((e) => {return e}) to the end

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I was writing about that, but I used a more readable syntax

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `flat` and `flatMap` are still currently "experimental" and subject to change.

Answer (score 3):

> Although this works, it is clunky and requires `pop()` because it will return an array of arrays, ie: `["12/16/1988", "16/"]`, plus I need to call `flat` afterwards.

The regex `exec` method always has its match in the `0` property (assuming that it matches at all), you can just access that and push it to your array:

```js
let infoArr = [
  "1 Ben Howard 12/16/1988 apple",
  "2 James Smith 1/10/1999 orange",
  "3 Andy Bloss 10/25/1956 apple",
  "4 Carrie Walters 8/20/1975 peach",
  "5 Doug Jones 11/10/1975 peach"
];

function extractDates(arr){
  const dateRegex = /(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g;
  const dateArr = [];
  for (const str of arr){
    const date = /(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g.exec(str);
    dateArr.push(date[0]);
  }
  return dateArr;
}

console.log(extractDates(infoArr));
```

(of course you could also do the same in a `map` callback)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` rather than the loops to pair down the code. Just be careful to keep the `null` out of the array if there is no match.

```js
let infoArr = [
    "1 Ben Howard 12/16/1988 apple",
    "2 James Smith 1/10/1999 orange",
    "3 Andy Bloss 10/25/1956 apple",
    "4 Carrie Walters 8/20/1975 peach",
    "5 Doug Jones 11/10/1975 peach"
  ];
  
let regex = /(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}/g
let dates =  infoArr.reduce((arr, s) => arr.concat(s.match(regex) || []) , [])
console.log(dates)
```